# How to get the search count for a particular string from each and every line in a file using Unix?

Tags: unix, awk, grep

I am trying to search for a particular string in a Unix file from each and every line and error out those records. Can someone let me how can I improve my code which is as below. Also please share your thoughts if you have a better solution.

```
v_filename=$1;
v_new_file="new_file";
v_error_file="error_file";
echo "The input file name is $var1"

while read line
do
        echo "Testing $line"
        v_cnt_check=`grep ',' $line | wc -l`
        echo "Testing $v_cnt_check"
#       if [  $v_cnt_check > 2 ]; then
#       echo $line >> $v_error_file
#       else
#       echo $line >> $v_new_file
#       fi
done < $v_filename
```

Input:

```
1,2,3
1,2,3,4
1,2,3
```

Output:

```
(New file)
1,2,3
1,2,3 

(Error file)
1,2,3,4
```

Comment: Post some sample input and expected output as it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: So, judging from the input and output, you want to eliminate every line that does not have three comma-separated fields on it, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F ',' -v new_file="$v_new_file" -v err_file="$v_error_file" \
    'BEGIN { OFS="," }
     NF == 3 { print >new_file }
     NF != 3 { print >err_file }' $v_filename
```

The first line sets the file name variables and sets the field separator to comma. The second line sets the output field separator to comma too.  The third line prints lines with 3 fields to the new file; the fourth line prints lines with other than 3 fields to the error file.

Note that your code would be excruciatingly slow on big files because it executes two processes per line.  This code has only one process operating on the whole file — which will be really important if the input grow to thousand or millions or more lines.

Comment: You are awesome dude. <Thumbs up>

Comment: Can't we use grep command to search for a string within a line and also with the help of while loops?

Comment: If you want to, yes, you may use `grep`.  It isn't the best way to do it, but you can if you want to. Note that `grep -c` counts the number of lines with the pattern match, not the number of matches on a single line.  Therefore you'd have to do some fancy trickery to get the count of the number of fields in the input line.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan.. I still haven't got that trickery in using grep to search for a character in a particular line. Looks like grep alone can't do that..

Comment: I agree that `grep` alone is insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

From the grep manpage:

```
   General Output Control
   -c, --count
          Suppress normal output; instead print a count of matching lines for each input file.  With the -v, --invert-match  option  (see  below),  count  non-
          matching lines.  (-c is specified by POSIX.)
```

You could do something like:

```
grep --count "your pattern" v_filename
```

to get the number of occurrences.  If you just want the number of lines with your pattern, replace the grep shown above with:

```
grep "your pattern" v_filename | wc -l
```